# SQL migration tool to use with DVCS

Tags: sql, database-migration

Most (if not all) of existing migration tools think that migration history is linear. So when you create new migration, you get version 42 or whatever, and then everybody can update to this version after receiving your changes.

The problem is that if you are using DVCS, two people could have version 42 in the same time. Which means that conflict resolving will become sufficiently non-trivial to be painful. :)

So my question is - should I roll my own system or is there anything in the wild? Preferably simple, friendly to *nix. I'm planning to use this mostly with mysql and postgresql.

Comment: From what I have seen, DVCSs use hashes as version numbers so these are very unlikely to be identical across trees.

Comment: DVCS - yes, but this has nothing in common with migrations.

Comment: In the end I wrote my own utility - http://github.com/piranha/nomad

Answer (score 0):

In Rails, the way this gets handled is by appending the date to the beginning of the file, in the form of `YYYYMMDDHHMMSS_migration_descriptor.rb`.

It then keeps track of which migrations have been applied in a table, by keeping track of the version numbers.  This allows you to run migrations on a table with a "lower" version number than the most recent change, thus greatly simplifying DVCS problems.

You might not be using Rails, but I think the way they solve this problem is pretty nice.  You can read more about Rails migrations [on the API docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Migration.html), or [on the Rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html).

Comment: Let's imagine a situation: I created migration on 15th of May and my colleague on 17th of May. His change was much simpler and so was done and accepted earlier than mine. His change is already applied to live db and now my change was accepted. What to do?

Comment: I've already said.  :-).  The migration tool will keep track in a table which migrations have been applied.  In this instance, suppose your change is `20110515143654_add_column_foo.rb`, and his is `20110517102341_add_product_table.rb`.  The tool looks at the date part of the filename, looks this up in the table it has, sees that 20110517102341 (his change) has been applied, but 20110515143654 (your change) has not, so it applies 20110515143654.  As for if it can "merge" migrations that effect the same parts of tables, I don't remember off the top of my head, but I presume it will not.

Comment: Ah, so ultimately it stores all migrations applied, not a number. Ok, that's what I need, just outside from Rails... :)